# What units does $x-y$ have if $x$ and $y$ are in °C?

Tags: temperature, units, dimensional-analysis

So in equations (for example $Q=mc\Delta T$) one normally has °C divided by °C, giving a result with no temperature units in its dimensionality. So, does °C $-$ °C also give a result with no temperature units? Because in the very same equation I used as an example ($Q=mc\Delta T$) the $\Delta T$ part equals $T_\mathrm{final}-T_\mathrm{initial}$, with both terms in °C.

And shouldn't that equal - whatever number it is going to equal with **no** °C sign?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132720/how-do-you-add-temperatures https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278678/degree-celsius-vs-celsius-degree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(x\,^\circ\mathrm C)-(y\,^\circ\mathrm C) = (x-y)\,^\circ\mathrm C$, because it is a linear unit.

Comment: yes, but one could also argue that $(x\,^\circ\mathrm C)-(y\,^\circ\mathrm C) = (x-y)\,\mathrm K$

Comment: Change in temperature is same on kelvin and Celsius scale. How does that matter? @AccidentalFourierTransform

Comment: What are linear units?