# What is the difference between degree celsius and celsius degree?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, terminology, conventions, units

It seems similar but can you guys please answer it that what is a specific difference between degree celsius and celsius degree?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Degree celsius vs. Celsius degree](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/278678/)

Answer (score 2):

"Degrees Celsius" is used to indicate a single temperature. As in, "water boils at $100$ degrees Celsius".

"Celsius degrees" is used for temperature differences. As in, "There are $10$ Celsius degrees between the inside temperature and the outside temperature."

Note that this is not really standard. I think people usually just use "degrees Celsius".

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this convention is not universally respected, and is not even mentioned in many introductory texts.

Comment: Aaron Stevens thank you so much

Comment: @dmckee That makes a lot of sense; because this is literally the first I've ever heard of it.  (and when I googled "celsius degree" I actually found a dupe of this as one of the first hits)

Comment: @JMac I didn’t encounter it until I was teaching. But I think I approve and have been slowly adding to my own writing.

Comment: A more common example of the same word reversal would be, for example:" Go 35 miles along the Interstate to Mile 54."